# Why are DBT teste creating audit tables with a unique identifier in the suffix, when using --store-failures flag?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, dbt

I'm running dbt test with the `--store-failure` flag, but its creating audit tables with unique identifier as the table name, instead of the table name itself.

Example:

`dbt_test__audit.source_not_null_my_schema_d29191aff8f71d8f3b84416a167e7f7a`

I'm using dbt with spark.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be misunderstanding what `--store-failures` does.
Say there is an `id` column of `mytbl` that I want to test to ensure it is unique. If I call `dbt test -m mytbl --store-failures` I am asking to dbt to create a table that includes the rows of `mytbl` where `id` is not unique, instead of just printing that information to the console.

So it creates a table that includes:

- the name of the .`yml` file where the test was defined,
- the table name and column name, and
- a guid associated with the specific `dbt test` you just called.

That way I can query my failures after the fact instead of having to scroll and hunt for the errors in the console and deal w/ the issues one at a time.

[The docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/tests#storing-test-failures) have great information on this:

> Normally, a test query will calculate failures as part of its
> execution. If you set the optional --store-failures flag or
> store_failures config, dbt will first save the results of a test query
> to a table in the database, and then query that table to calculate the
> number of failures.
>
> This workflow allows you to query and examine failing records much
> more quickly in development

Does that make sense?